# Inserting a figure below a text without starting a new page

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, signatures

I'd like to insert a figure at the end of a page without that this figure appears in the next page.
The last text of the page is the following and the figure should go below this text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }

\begin{document}
here there is a long text
\begin{flushright}
Signature
\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Firma}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

The above code puts the text in a page and the figure in the next page, but i don't want to start a new page.

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Please prepare a complete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Probably the images is too large for the remaining space?

Comment: Hello @leandriis i edited my question.

Comment: If I add `\name{first}{last}` to make your example compilable and if I add `demo` as a class option because I don't have your image file available, I get the following single page output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SumVl.png

Comment: @leandriis should i also add the long text?

Comment: There is nothing in the code that you show that is forcing a page break so presumably it is just that the figure doesn't fit on the page and you get the normal automatic page breaking. what happens if you change the scale to scale=0.1?  presumably it fits and then you can increase it and at some point it will not fit on that page and will go to the next.

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle, yes it's a  problem of automatic page breaking. Is there a way to prevent this only when i put a specific figure? The page should end with a figure outside the canonical margins.

Comment: put `\vspace*{-2cm}` after the image or use `\enlargethispage{2cm}` to make that page a bit bigger or ...  But really you should ask about _that_ but you do not mention that in your question at all. The fact that it is an image is not relevant you could just as easily have the text `ZZZ`  on that line instead of `\includegraphics` you are just asking about how to make the page extend beyond the bottom margin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fantastic solution. Thank you very very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to the image, the page breaking logic would be the same if you had text on that line.  To prevent a page break you need to hide the height of the content or make the page bigger. LaTeX has a standard command to do the latter: if you add

```
  \enlargethispage{2cm}
```

somewhere on the first page then the content will be allowed to extend into the bottom margin by 2cm.